# Android toolchain for kernel and user space

Tags: android, android-source, gnu-toolchain

I understand AOSP comes with a prebuilt toolchain. Also there are other standalone toolchains that can be used. I understand that we can use these toolchains and compile the AOSP code (without kernel).

When we download the kernel for a particular device and want to compile the kernel, do we need to use the same toolchain that we used to build the user space framework?

Or to be specific, I have a GNU based toolchain `arm-linux-*-gnueabi` for compiling kernel. Do I need to use the same toolchain for cross compiling the AOSP code?

Comment: Its depends to your CPU type. If its something custom its 100% true. In case of x86_64 arc it depends.